# Is the verb 'let' transitive or intransitive?

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

Is the verb 'let', with the meaning 'to cause to', transitive or intransitive? E.g.:

> Do you want to go out for a pizza? Please *let know*.

Is this allowed or is it misuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is transitive (see sense 2 [here](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/let_1)). The sentence *please let know* is non-standard.

Comment: Yes, it should of course be "let me know" and is then obviously transitive. +1

Comment: @[Brett Reynolds] +1 Thanks! But what do you mean by "non-standard"? Is it colloquial, slang, misuse or something else?

Comment: I mean, for most English-speakers it would be ungrammatical.